# Access 2013 data types

Tags: sql, ms-access

I just started using Access 2013 and there are two new data types, Short Text and Long Text.  I need to programatically add a table in SQL and I used to use `TEXT(100)` or something like it, but what do I use to create a column of type `Long Text`?  I need the field to be like the memo type in previous versions of Access, basically limitless or very large.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Long Text` just like the `memo type`:

> In earlier version (before A2007) we had the RTF presentation for Memo
>   fields. The implementation was - IIRC - storing the text you had on
>   the screen in Word RTF format with some cryptic codes in {} to
>   indicate the formatting. In A2007 they changed to the new formatting
>   known as Rich Text. This is stored in the Memo field with HTML tags
>   implement the formatting. The thing they changed now is not the UI for
>   these fields but the name of the datatype in the database. It's not
>   called MEMO anymore, now it's called LONG TEXT. The formatted text
>   should AFAIK still be stored in the same way, as HTML coded text. When
>   you switch from plain text to rich text you do nothing else then tell
>   Access to use another UI to display the content of the data in the
>   database. Stored is still the same.

You can read more from [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/accessdev/thread/db74d3c8-6068-46b9-bffb-a1d3953a9ac5/)

Answer (score 0):

Oops, I found it.  It's just LONGTEXT.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms714540(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms714540%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)